# Iterate over SQLOBJECT -WEBSQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-sql

I want to iterate over a SQLObject in javascript.I have some data in a WEBSQL database in the browser.

Until now I was rendering in React like this

```
var list = data.map(function(film){
    return <li key={film.ID}>
               {film.NAME}
            </li>;
  },this);

return (
  <div>
    <ul className="table-view">
      {list}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

However,I can't do this with this type of object.

How can I do it without putting the HTML inside string.

I want to avoid iterating with for then adding the results to a string object

Comment: What HTML do you want to avoid putting inside of a string? There isn't any obvious string manipulation in the code you provided. The `data` function shouldn't be returning a string either if this is typical ReactJS code.

Comment: I want to return li elements

Comment: You're likely returning React's elements, which are `LI` elements. If it's returned as an array, the it's usable via the `{ list }` syntax you've used.

Comment: there's some of my code in my question wrong,I'm gonna edit it

Comment: Using the map function gives me an error saying Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: Where does the variable `data` come from? It needs to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use map function to iterate and return Array of Components.

Alternate way is to use dangerouslyInsertedHTML or dangerouslySetHTML in div tag. You can check this how it can be done. You can use for Loop to iterate over the array of object and generate your HTML as string appended to the previous object. Click [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)!

Thanks,
Ankit.